# What do you call a space or a mini room between flats?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

For instance, there's a floor and there are four flats on it. Two of them are enclosed with an extra room where both flats can leave their shoes or save supply meters. What do you call this room?

[image: Floor plan]

Comment: Please explain what you mean by “save supply meters”.

Comment: Assuming mean *what* you should call it (broom closet, meter room, etc) and not *how* (phone, intercom, etc), it might help for you to link to a floor plan that has such a room drawn.

Comment: Consider "a common area".

Comment: It  is  difficult  to  explain  but very often  flats  have  supply meters  outside ,  somewhere  next  to the stairwell. So  ,  some  people think that  it's  not good  because any hooligan can come and  break  it down just  for a  sake of vandalism,  so  they agree  to enclose  it and be happy. It's not a hundred percent a supply room this way.

Comment: https://pp.userapi.com/c834104/v834104655/13a24a/aXpCzF3Uzzg.jpg here's  a  plan  of  such  a  floor

Comment: Please explain “supply meter” does it measure supplies? What is a supply? I imagine that is is stuff like food, and ammunition. That is what we used to keep in the supply room. Though I would imagine that you don't keep ammunition in it. But where does the meter come in. (Having written this, I think that I am completely wrong, but have no idea what the correct answer is.)

Comment: http://s18694.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/metre.jpg this  is  what I think  a supply  meter is. I  might be  wrong  at  naming  though.  In  the  scheme  for  the flat one  and  two  it  is  inside  that enclosed arear.  For the flat three  and  four  it's  just  in  the  stairwell  as  it's not  enclosed. ..

Comment: I would tend to call it a "utility room".

Comment: (Note that such terms are highly localized, and almost certainly vary between the US and the UK.)

Comment: @HotLicks's note is a good point - in British English a *utility room* is a laundry room (US English) inside the property, usually off the kitchen.  Other cleaning materials are likely to be stored there, and all the ones I've seen have had overflow kitchen equipment storage.  Where I lived with a *laundry room* that was communal, in a building full of student flats

Answer (score 1):

The above describes a **communal area**.

> **Communal areas** are those parts of a house, block of flats, street or estate which tenants have a right to use in common with other tenants and for which a landlord is responsible.

[Harrogate Council](https://www.harrogate.gov.uk/info/20065/council_housing_repairs/500/communal_areas_in_council_housing/1)

> Fire safety In communal areas of our blocks of flats

[Thames Valley Housing](https://www.tvha.co.uk/customer-services/your-home/safety/communal/keeping-communal-areas-clear-of-all-items/)

> Safety in communal areas

[Nottingham Metropolitan](https://www.metropolitan.org.uk/images/CUST043_0413_Communal-Areas-Safety-Leaflet-V11-M-Web-AW.pdf)

Comment: Could this just be a Harrogation?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Harrogance?

Comment: Some tenants were evicted, I hear, during an outbreak of _Harrogaphobia_.

Comment: Seriously, this could be a niche usage from the quote given. It's not, but more evidence is needed.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The term is in common use; we use it in our work with Homeless Hostels for Gloucester City Council. I have added two more references.

Comment: Much better. Even if I can't pun those.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, a space that is shared between tenants is a **common area** (or **common room**). This is often used in the sense of a shared recreational space, but it can also be a generic term for any room or area that is communal in some sense. (It will often be used on blueprints without a designated purpose, aside from the fact that multiple parties can make use of it.)

However, specific instances may be referred to differently—for example, a  *shared toilet* or *communal storage*. I have not heard of a word or phrase for a space specific to a utility meter—or to shoes . . .

Comment: Alright,  Jason.  So it  is  just  called  a  common room or  a utility.  I  mean  in  the  everyday  life.  So  cool  :D